# IBOutlets set up and working correctly are suddenly all shown as "!" in interface builder

Tags: ios5, properties, interface-builder, xcode4.5, iboutlet

While updating a UIViewController, all my IBOutlets are suddenly not registering with Interface builder. (note: i did not change any of these outlets in the .m file)

The class in the identity inspector is correct, the IBOutlets are shown as connected in the .m file and the app still runs fine.

However, I cannot add any new ones or edit the current ones. Whats happened here and how do i go about correcting it?

[image: InterfaceBuilder Connections][image: mFile]

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the solution. It was as simple as closing x-code and opening it again. Not sure why this happened in the first place, might be a bug, but if anyone gets the problem try that first.